# How to localize label content with underscore

Tags: wpf, xaml, location, label

I'm trying to localize label with underscore helper (Alt). This example works fine but without localization.

Without localization:

```
<Label Content="_Name: "
       Target="{Binding ElementName=TextBoxName}" />
```

I want something like that:

```
 <Label Content="{x:Static loc:Localization.Name}"
               ContentStringFormat=" _{0}"
               Target="{Binding ElementName=TextBoxName}" />
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: I have no problems with the localized version (tested with WPF .Net Core 3.0), but to me, the responsibility for the underscore is inside localization.

Comment: BTW Did you compile/rebuild the solution before testing?

Comment: ok thats the problem, clever solution thanks